# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl http://soap.m4u.com.au/?wsdl

Need to call "sendMessages"  method but I am getting following error every time.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service
```

My client file code is :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://soap.m4u.com.au/?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
$params = array(
      "authentication" => array(
        "userId" => "******",
        "password" => "********"
      ),
      "requestBody" => array(
        "messages" => array(
            "message" => array(
                "sequenceNumber"=>"1",
                "recipients" => array(
                    "recipient" => array(
                        "999966663333"
                    )
                ),
                "content" => "Message Content"
            )
        )
      )

);  

$response = $client->__soapCall("sendMessages", array($params));
```

**Update**
This web-service using SOAP 1.1 not SOAP 1.2, when I changed I got following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] The request is either not well-formed or is not valid against the relevant schema.
```

Comment: Problem is in your client definition. Paste your code where you have defined $client.And why aren't you catching this exception? wrap your client call in try catch block.you wil get exact error.

Comment: I have already added please check.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://soap.m4u.com.au/?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
```

Replcae this line,

Correction: "soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1

This service is using SOAP 1.1 not SOAP 1.2

**Edited:**

Now problem is in your request message structure. That content field is under messages. BTW, your final soap request should be like this,

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns="http://xml.m4u.com.au/2009">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:sendMessages>
     <ns:authentication>
        <ns:userId>?</ns:userId>
        <ns:password>?</ns:password>
     </ns:authentication>
     <ns:requestBody>
        <ns:messages sendMode="normal">
           <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
           <ns:message format="SMS" sequenceNumber="0">
              <!--You may enter the following 7 items in any order-->
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:origin>?</ns:origin>
              <ns:recipients>
                 <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                 <ns:recipient uid="0">?</ns:recipient>
              </ns:recipients>
              <ns:content>?</ns:content>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:scheduled>?</ns:scheduled>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:deliveryReport>false</ns:deliveryReport>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:validityPeriod>169</ns:validityPeriod>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:tags>
                 <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                 <ns:tag name="?">?</ns:tag>
              </ns:tags>
           </ns:message>
        </ns:messages>
     </ns:requestBody>
  </ns:sendMessages>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

you can ignore optional field in above request. FYI.. I have generated it from soap ui. Let me know your further issues.

One more thing, If you will wrap your client soap call in try block and catch it in your code, you wont get these unhandled exception, for example:

```
try{
       $response = $client->__soapCall("sendMessages", array($params));           
   }
catch (SoapFault $exception) {

echo $exception;
```

}

Comment: I have changed that but now getting following error
`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] The request is either not well-formed or is not valid against the relevant schema.`